# Why does my PC keep disconnecting & reconnecting to my wireless network?

Tags: 11.10, wireless, cisco

I seem to be having a bit of trouble here, as my Cisco AM10 USB Wi-Fi adapter keeps circling through a loop of connecting & disconnecting from my wireless home network.  The network router is a Cisco Valet Plus (Cisco M20), and it works perfectly on my copy of Windows 7 Home Premium, but when I boot into Ubuntu 11.10 (I have a dual-boot configuration on my home PC), it loops around and around trying to connect, connecting, disconnecting, and I would greatly appreciate any help that anyone can provide.

How can I fix this (annoying) problem???

Thanks in advance, everyone!!

Comment: please can you add the output of `sudo lshw -class network` and `rfkill list all` to your question.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons for that, possible causes:

1. your disk have hardware failure, like I/O errors...
2. You have multiple firewalls enabled, and it is better to have only one, maybe "gufw" is the best... and it needs to deny all with rules to allow out udp 53 and allow out tcp 25,53,80,110,143,993,5060
3. Your OS is not with all modules inserted, type: lsmod > list1.txt
   Then create an USB installer with the "startup disk creator" using the ISO of your installation CD (a pen of 2 GB is enough) then boot from that USB PEN and choose "try Ubuntu" and type there: lsmod > list2.txt and copy this file to the same location the one above and open  both in text editor and see if there is missing modules in list1.txt...
   To install missing modules use first modinfo  after the description see if it needs dependencies and install those first if not, just copy the full path of the ko file and type sudo insmod , after all modules inserted no need for reboot things should start working fine...

Comment: something missing from my post: To install missing modules use first modinfo <name of the module> after the description see if it needs dependencies and install those first if not, just copy the full path of the ko file and type sudo insmod <paste path/file.ko>, after all modules inserted no need for reboot things should start working fine...

Answer (score 0):

I would start with this troubleshooting guide

https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

go to --System Settings--Network--wireless--options--IPV6 Settings

untick Require IPV6 addressing for this connection to complete.

It worked for me.